# Make App available for different languages

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, marketplace

I finished a new WP7 app and I made it possible to switch to different languages via custom code.
I'd like to add English and French, currently it is only set to German.

When I try to submit it to the marketplace, I only have the option to fill out the german info, but how can I declare my app to be also available in EN and FR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to Anton** I came to the solution:

If you end up like me, do this to add different language support for your app manually (without filling out resources):

Create new resource items in your project and call them AppResources.en-GB.resx etc. It should fit to the syntax. You don't need to fill out or explicitly use those resource files.

After that, you go to your .csproj file of your project and add (see above posts) those language infos into it. Then, you'll see that the marketplace recognizes those languages.

Answer (score 2):

See the [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx): on MSDN.

The idea: If you have resources for supported languages, you need to declare them in **.csproj** file

```
<SupportedCultures>de-DE;fr-FR;us-EN;</SupportedCultures>
```

Comment: Will these languages be detected when I submit a this single XAP to the marketplace? Because the last time I checked, I just got German detected.

Comment: When you go to marketplace (from the phone) and check the app, you can find supported languages region in a description. You'll see there all languages you added to proj file.

Comment: I am talking about submitting the app to the Windows Dev Center, pal.
Would this SupportCultures-Tag let the App-Submission detect that this Apps holds three languages?

Comment: Yes, it would. But, if you not sure - let me check it in my company account on monday :)

Comment: I was sure before you asked again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.
When I submit this to the marketplace, only German gets detected.

I did add `<SupportedCultures>de-DE;fr-FR;us-EN;</SupportedCultures>` to the .csproj file

Comment: It should work. Did you use the localization system from the link in my answer? If yes - marketplace will detect the languages, and suggest you to fill description for 3 langs.